# How to append URLs to an array in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I append URLs to a array in python, I was trying using the following code,

```
zone = ["z1", "z2", "z3"]
result_1 = []

for i in zone:
    result_val = os.system("gcloud command1 " +i+ " --command2")
    result_1.append(result_val)
print(result_1)
```

But when run this, my results are printing like below,

```
https://sample-domain.com/test/abc/1
https://sample-domain.com/test/abc/2
https://sample-domain.com/test/abc/3
```

But when I print the "result_1" it shows me below result

```
[0, 0, 0]
```

But I need the result like this,

```
["https://sample-domain.com/test/abc/1","https://sample-domain.com/test/abc/2","https://sample-domain.com/test/abc/3"]
```

How can I correct this issue ?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: What's the exact command you're running there? The result is the exit error (0) that you add to the list.

Comment: @baduker I get `512` as result, instead of a link

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code to append to append to your list (we don't call it an array). The problem is that `result_val` is not the string that is printed by the command you are running - the output has **nothing to do with** the `os.system` function, just like how `print` and `return` have nothing to do with each other. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4760215 (I am out of duplicate close votes for today).

Answer (score 1):

You need to store in your list the standard output.
What you are doing now is only storing the return code.

It is possible to obtain a similar result using Popen from subprocess.

```
import subprocess

zone = ["z1", "z2", "z3"]
result_1 = []

for i in zone:
    proc = subprocess.Popen(["gcloud", "command1", i , "--command2"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    for line in iter(proc.stdout.readline, ''):
        result_1.append(line.rstrip())
print(result_1)
```

Answer (score -1):

You may want to use `.check_output` from `subprocess` module, as the comments suggest, you need to get the output printed in the console, not the result of `os.system()`, which returns a different value:

```
import subprocess

zone = ["z1", "z2", "z3"]
result_1 = []

for i in zone:
    res = subprocess.check_output(["gcloud", "command1", i, "--command2"])
    result_1.append(res)
print(result_1)
```

Comment: Not sure, but the `.stdout` in `res.stdout` seems odd: Doesn't `subprocess.check_output()` return bytes?

Comment: @Timus Indeed; updated the answer

Comment: @tripleee Thanks for the edit, I wasn't sure about `.stdout` function usage in this case